# Are there disadvantages to the Assault Weapons Ban of 2013? If so, what?

Tags: united-states, guns

The first [Federal Assault Weapons Ban](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Assault_Weapons_Ban) was enacted in 1994 and expired in 2004. A new [Assault Weapons Ban of 2013](https://www.govtrack.us/congress/bills/113/hr437) is being [proposed](http://www.feinstein.senate.gov/public/index.cfm/assault-weapons-ban-summary). **What are the disadvantages of the Assault Weapons Ban of 2013, if any?** (Examples from the 1994 version that would apply to the new 2013 bill are welcome.)

Comment: Why are you assuming there are disadvantages?

Comment: @YannisRizos, I am not. I am only interested in the disadvantages, since I already linked to/am aware of the advantages.

Comment: @yannisrizos though user 1873 often asks questions with an implicit bias, I don't think that this is one of them. Asking about the disadvantages of a law does not necessarily imply that there are disadvantages. A perfectly acceptable answer could be "there are no disadvantages", so long as you could support that.

Comment: @Avi, absolutely. If someone could show that the previous 1994 law had no disadvantages, and the new law has the same (or very similar) provisions, I would find "no disadvantages" an acceptable answer.

Comment: @user1873 - I edited to try and strike a more neutral tone - effectively, not presupposing that there are disadvantages, since you'll accept "none" as an answer.

Comment: Disadvantages for whom? The weapons producers may be in disadvantage due to revenue drop.

Comment: @Anixx, or a revenue increase due to collectors who want to have an "illegal" gun  before they are declared illegal.

Comment: @user1873 interesting perspective.  Though off-topic to the question, we may then see cycles of re-design and re-ban, which would be an inadvertent economic stimulous

Comment: @NewAlexandria, the comment was specificly directed at Anixx's "weapon producers **may** be disadvantaged," I was just indicating that his assumption may not be likely.

Comment: @user1873 why collectors would need illegal guns?

Comment: @Anixx because they're harder to obtain

Comment: @SamIam - We should outlaw some matchbox cars then </collector>

Comment: @DVK "hard to obtain" isn't why they should be outlawed, it's why `collectors would need` them

Comment: @SamIam - duh..

Answer (score 5):

**There are disadvantages to everything.**

It's reasonable to assume that fewer assault weapons will be sold, which is a disadvantage if you are a manufacturer or dealer of assault weapons. It is possible that some may go out of business, or lay off workers. There might be some other negative effect on the economy - probably very small. Likewise those who organize recreational firing of assault weapons will either have to stop, or face more licensing restrictions.

If you are a person who wishes to own an assault weapon, then this ban curtails your ability to do so.

As is usual in politics, it is not a question of whether or not there are any disdvantages, but of balancing the advantages and the disadvantages.

Answer (score 3):

This is the disadvantage of an "Assault Weapons Ban:"

1. The AWB doesn't apply to criminals.
2. It would create a Black Market, because anytime a product that's in demand gets banned, someone is going to step in to meet that demand. And with that demand comes a lot of bloodshed. Just look at the Prohibition and the War on Drugs.
3. Doesn't solve a gun violence, because you can't legislate behavior. Just look at all the mass shootings. What's the common factor? They were social outcasts. And I refuse to call these "mass shootings," because it doesn't designate that the shooter hit/killed anything. So out of all the "mass murders/massacres," only one involved the use of an AR-15 (Aurora, Colorado).

Comment: Actually the AWB does apply to criminals. Some of them just disobey it.

Comment: "Doesn't solve a gun violence, because you can't legislate behavior." is a standard false argument. Following that argument, what's the point of making murder illegal, since "you can't legislate behaviour". Murderers are just going to keep murdering. And the "Don't ban it because it would create a black market" would lead you to legalize child pornography, nuclear materials and heroin, because "otherwise you'll just have it on the black market".

Answer (score 1):

**The primary disadvantage I've seen is that this bill includes no solution / countermeasure to also support the previous form of arms acquisition.**

---

Such a countermeasure could come in the form of a licensure provision for owning the type of item whose general-ban is proposed.

E.G. the arms and arms-accessories could be moved into the [Class C license](http://www.atf.gov/firearms/how-to/become-an-ffl.html), or a new class designed for this middle-ground.

In other words, this bill proposes to ***limit a constitutional right*** (remove aspects of its practice) without simultaneously proposing an alternative or remediative course of action for those that wish to maintain all allowed dimensions of said right.

Comment: You have a quote block in light orange, but no linked source that it belongs to. Where is the source of the quote? You are saying the disadvantage is that you cannot apply for a permit to own a gun banned by the Assault Weapon Ban 2014. Since it is impossible to get the government to permit you to do something that was previously legal, those people who do own those guns will be disadvantaged.

Comment: I don't use quote blocks for literal quotations - just as a formatting element to highlight text.  A code-block formatting seems out-of-place on this site

Comment: but yes, to the second-half of your comment.  That is what I am saying is the disadvantage

Comment: I downvoted this answer, and I'll tell you Why.  Coming into this question, I know pretty much nothing about the `Assault Weapons Ban of 2013`, and After reading the answer, I still feel as though I know nothing of the `Assault Weapons Ban of 2013`.  Or, to put it another way, I generally expect to learn something from reading answers, and in this case I didn't

Comment: *So it is my fault that you don't want to read the links provided in the question?*  I read the linked bill, summary, and related info, learned the specific text of the bill, and replied.

Comment: @NewAlexandria - You should define "Previous form of ownership".  If you're going to say that this *removes* a constitutional right, rather than *limits* one, you should clearly spell out how it does so.  "You may be prosecuted for anything you say" is very different from "You can't threaten the President", but both nominally violate the First Amendment.

Comment: @Bobson I've changed the text "remove" since that it's the way it should be straightforwardly-interpreted.  The removal is only on certain facets of the practice of the right, as per your presidential-threat analogy.  I have also changed "ownership" to "acquisition"

Comment: your answer is still almost exclusively about what is not in the act, without context, that kind information doesn't mean anything to the reader.  Sure,  we can probably parse the context by following various links, but after a time, many links can go dead.   Either your answer or the question or both should at least summarize the relevant context, so that this answer can still mean something when the links go dead.

Comment: @SamIam *it is a bill before the Senate*.  Any summarization is almost *guaranteed* to be biased, even neutrally by convenience.  Actually, I don't like Feinstein's summary that is linked, but I grant that it is, at least, something... yet I wouldn't draw attention to it because of its faults (she prefers the bill as-is).  Federal law is complex stuff - you have to do your own thinking.  I would love the link of summarization system you hope for, but I can't give it to you today, on every issue

Comment: The fact that the law is complex makes it **more** important to summarize the parts that you think are important for your answer.

Comment: And I wouldn't worry about showing bias If I were you.  It's the extrapolation and interpretation of the consequences of the law that carry the highest risk of bias, which your question mostly is in the first place.

Comment: @SamIamI did summarize *what the bill is missing*.  That is, after all, what the question asked about.  I disagree the interpretation is more important that the text of the law.  They are both equal partners in liberty or crime

Comment: Wandering back through old questions...  This answer has been revised to the point that I think it deserves an upvote now.  Much better than the last time I looked at it.